# How to connect multiple ground pins in a FFC connector

Tags: grounding, ground-plane, fpc, ffc, multi-layer

[image]

So I have a bunch of these FFC connectors shown here, and a lot of the middle pins are actually ground pins (highlighted in green). I have a multi-layer board, so I want to route all these grounds to an internal layer. Do I need to run separate tracks from each pin and then use separate vias to go the internal layer? Or I can short them all by running a trace across them and then use a single fat via to go the next layer?

Sorry I'm a complete newbie to PCB design, I don't have much idea about proper routing techniques.

Answer (score 1):

I would run a (fairly wide) trace parallel to the ground pins, then use thin traces to connect those pins to the ground trace.

The reason for this is so that those pins solder correctly.

The wider trace can connect to whichever layer you desire with one or more vias.

Answer (score 1):

There's no absolute answer here, but you probably want to keep the paths as short as possible

So use as many vias as you can fit, perhaps joining them into small groups with top layer planes (but don't forget the thermal relief to make it solderable...)